# Invalid model event is not fired in the ItemView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have defined the following events in an ItemView:

```
modelEvents: {
            "change": "refresh",
            "invalid": "handleValidation"
        }
```

and the validate function in my Model is:

```
validate: function(attrs) {
            if(attrs.Code == "")
                return "Error in Code field";
            else if(attrs.Name == "")
                return "Error in Name field";
        }
```

The problem is that when I save an instance of my model, validate function is called  in the model and returns string messages succesfully, but the invalid event in the ItemView is not fired.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the code for the listener in your View, can you post it? i.e. listenTo(this.model, 'invalid', myHandler);

Comment: Hi, the code for the listener is the section called modelEvents above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have right now should be working. There must be some disconnect in the code that you've provided. I've create a simple JSFiddle that samples the functionality you're wanting: http://jsfiddle.net/craigjennings11/DZtDm/

```
var View = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    el: '#content',
    template: _.template('<button>Hello World</button>'),
    events: {
        'click button': 'tryToSave'
    },
    modelEvents: {
        'invalid': 'failedValidation'
    },
    tryToSave: function() {
        this.model.save();
    },
    failedValidation: function(err) {
        this.$el.append('<div>' + err.validationError + '</div>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should trigger 'invalid' event and return error meggase as attribute.

```
validate: function(attrs) {
        if(attrs.Code == "")
            this.trigger('invalid', 'Error in Code field');

        else if(attrs.Name == "")
           this.trigger('invalid', 'Error in Name field');
    }
```

Like this.

Comment: That worked for me.Thank you very much. Although now, the event invalid is firing, my model is saved. Is it supposed to prevent model from saving if invalid is fired?

Comment: There's no need to manually trigger this event because Backbone automatically handles triggering it in the case of a failed validation.